# Error after changing which Scene has to go first in GameViewController

Tags: swift, xcode, sprite-kit

I have created a HomeScene.sks and a HomeScene.swift. In the GameViewController I've changed the default "GameScene" to "HomeScene" like this"

```
   override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    if let view = self.view as! SKView? {
        // Load the SKScene from 'HomeScene.sks'
        if let scene = SKScene(fileNamed: "HomeScene") {
            // Set the scale mode to scale to fit the window
            scene.scaleMode = .aspectFill

            // Present the scene
            view.presentScene(scene)
        }

        view.ignoresSiblingOrder = true

        view.showsFPS = true
        view.showsNodeCount = true
    }
}
```

When I run it in the Simulator it shows the LaunchScreen but than it stops. In my xcode output screen I see:

> 2017-05-22 21:02:07.910 DiceWar[88707:2060079] -[DiceWar.HomeScene setNormalTexture:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fdba6008af0
>   2017-05-22 21:02:07.915 DiceWar[88707:2060079] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[DiceWar.HomeScene setNormalTexture:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fdba6008af0'

I Googled around but can't find anything useful. What are these lines telling me? Did I use a bad texture? I also tried to message out all the code in HomeScene.swift but the error still occurs.

I'm not sure if it's because English isn't my native language or if it's my logic but I really don't understand what xcode is trying to tell me.

**Edit**
I think I found it. Because there was something with a texture. I deleted a Color Sprite from the HomeScene.sks and now it does start. When I replaced the Color Sprite there wasn't a problem until I used this line:

```
settingsButton = self.childNode(withName: "settingsButton") as! SKSpriteNode
```

The strange thing is, I used the exact some line for another image (instead of settingsButton I used playButton) The playButton line doesn't seem to be a problem.

Comment: Enter a line of the print statement in the didMove method to see if the app really reaches HomeScene.swift.

Comment: I did and it doesn't appear in the output. So HomeScene doesn't load at all.

Answer (score 0):

The error message is saying that your application logic is trying to call `setNormalTexture(_:)` on your class `DiceWar.HomeScene`, but that class does not know how to handle that method call.

From the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/reference/spritekit/skaction/1417706-setnormaltexture):

> This action can only be executed by an SKSpriteNode object.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I used (command F) and searched every swift file in my project but I can't find setNormalTexture. So where is this being called from?

Comment: Try setting a symbolic breakpoint on `-[DiceWar.HomeScene setNormalTexture:]`?

Comment: Nothing appears with the breakpoint. It's the first time I'm using Symbolic Breakpoints but I don't see anything appear in the breakpoint tab. Isn't that strange? Because the error says it is being called but the breakpoint isn't saying it found one.